# KML File - Placemark Point - only the name, no icon

Tags: labeling, kml

I have generated a KML file (see below). My question is: how do I add definitions etc. in the file in order to remove the icons? I only want to display the name, for example A, B etc. I know this can be done in Google Earth but my use case is to generate the file with a program.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
 <Document>
  <open>1</open>
  <name>text</name>
  <Folder>
   <name>Grid</name>
   <Placemark>
    <name>A</name>
    <Point>
     <coordinates>17.78290100000001,59.51952679585495</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
    <name>B</name>
    <Point>
     <coordinates>17.78334264203328,59.51952679510959</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
    <name>C</name>
    <Point>
     <coordinates>17.783784284066495,59.519526792873464</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
    <name>D</name>
    <Point>
     <coordinates>17.78422592609964,59.51952678914665</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
    <name>E</name>
    <Point>
     <coordinates>17.78466756813268,59.51952678392921</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
    <name>F</name>
    <Point>
     <coordinates>17.785109210165544,59.51952677722101</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
    <name>G</name>
    <Point>
     <coordinates>17.785550852198252,59.519526769022065</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
    <name>H</name>
    <Point>
     <coordinates>17.785992494230708,59.51952675933237</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
    <name>I</name>
    <Point>
     <coordinates>17.78643413626291,59.51952674815204</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
    <name>J</name>
    <Point>
     <coordinates>17.78687577829478,59.51952673548094</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
    <name>1</name>
    <Point>
     <coordinates>17.782680178983348,59.51963899981365</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
    <name>2</name>
    <Point>
     <coordinates>17.78268017751645,59.519863408097926</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
    <name>3</name>
    <Point>
     <coordinates>17.782680176049567,59.5200878163745</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
    <name>4</name>
    <Point>
     <coordinates>17.78268017458258,59.52031222464326</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
    <name>5</name>
    <Point>
     <coordinates>17.782680173115605,59.52053663290431</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
    <name>6</name>
    <Point>
     <coordinates>17.78268017164867,59.52076104115758</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
    <name>7</name>
    <Point>
     <coordinates>17.782680170181635,59.5209854494031</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
   <Placemark>
    <name>8</name>
    <Point>
     <coordinates>17.782680168714595,59.521209857640876</coordinates>
    </Point>
   </Placemark>
  </Folder>
 </Document>
</kml>
```

[image: Grid labels]

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add Style tags, containing an IconStyle tag, and then set the icon scale to zero.  This can be done either by putting a Style within each placemark, OR by defining one shared style at the top of the file, and then referencing it with a simple styleUrl tag in each placemark.

Here is a very basic example of what the style tag could look like:

```
<Style>
    <IconStyle>
        <scale>0</scale>
    </IconStyle>
</Style>
```

For more background on KML styles, including how to use shared styles, see the "Styles for Geometry" section of the KML tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#geometrystyles